S2S Connection in Pending Stuck, but only for certain contact records
I have an S2S Connection set up between two orgs, org A and org B.
As part of setting up org B, there are some contacts that we need to manually send from org A to org B. Every so often, this sync seems to get "stuck", where the status for the particular record is "Pending (sent)"

To note:

It seems to be just particular contact records (or random) - in the case below, I was able to successfully forward 10 other contact records within minutes.
I looked at the Connection History in both Org A and Org B, and no error messages were present.

Where does one look next to debug this?
